Removing ```json and ``` from Markdown
I have a result object from the code:
for fragment_string in fragment_strings:
    prompt = generate_prompt(fragment_string)
    messages = [{"role": "user", "content": prompt}]
    result = chat_completion(messages)
    
    # Post-process the response to remove the "json" prefix
    if result.strip().startswith("json"):
        result = result.strip()[4:].strip()
    
    print(f'{result} \n')

That looks like
```json
{
  "question": "What are the key findings and recommendations regarding the use of AI in clinical practice and the integration of smart devices for health monitoring?",
  "answer": "The key findings and recommendations regarding the use of AI in clinical practice and the integration of smart devices for health monitoring are as follows: 
  1. AI Applications in Clinical Practice:
     - Findings: The development of new techniques as established standards of care uses robust peer-reviewed R&D practices, providing safeguards against deceptive or poorly-validated AI algorithms. AI diagnostics replacing established medical standards will require extensive validation.
     - Recommendations: Support the preparation of promising AI applications for rigorous approval procedures needed for clinical practice. Create testing and validation approaches for AI algorithms to evaluate performance under conditions different from the training set.
  2. Confluence of AI and Smart Devices for Monitoring Health and Disease:
     - Findings: Revolutionary changes in health and health care are beginning with the use of smart devices to monitor individual health, often outside traditional clinical settings. AI and smart devices will become increasingly interdependent, with AI powering many health-related mobile devices and apps, and mobile devices generating massive datasets for AI-based health tools.
     - Recommendations: Support the development of AI applications that enhance the performance of new mobile monitoring devices and apps. Develop data infrastructure to capture and integrate data from smart devices to support AI applications. Ensure privacy and transparency in data use. Track developments in foreign health care systems for useful technologies and potential failures.",
  "fragments_needed": [
    {
      "index": "32",
      "content": "1. AI Applications in Clinical Practice\nFindings:\n● The process of developing a new technique as an established standard of care uses the robust practice of peer-reviewed R&D, and can provide safeguards against the deceptive or poorly-validated use of AI algorithms. (Section 2.3)\n● The use of AI diagnostics as replacements for established steps in medical standards of care will require far more validation than the use of such diagnostics to provide supporting information that aids in decisions. (Section 2.3)\nRecommendations:\n● Support work to prepare AI results for the rigorous approval procedures needed for acceptance for clinical practice. Create testing and validation approaches for AI algorithms to evaluate performance of the algorithms under conditions that differ from the training set. (Section 2.3)"
    },
    {
      "index": "32",
      "content": "2. Confluence of AI and Smart Devices for Monitoring Health and Disease\nFindings:\n● Revolutionary changes in health and health care are already beginning in the use of smart devices to monitor individual health. Many of these developments are taking place outside of traditional diagnostic and clinical settings. (Section 3.1)\n● In the future, AI and smart devices will become increasingly interdependent, including in health-related fields. On one hand, AI will be used to power many health-related mobile monitoring devices and apps. On the other hand, mobile devices will create massive datasets that, in theory, could open new possibilities in the development of AI-based health and health care tools. (Section 3.1)\nRecommendations:\n● Support the development of AI applications that can enhance the performance of new mobile monitoring devices and apps. (Section 3.1)\n● Develop data infrastructure to capture and integrate data generated from smart devices to support AI applications. (Section 3.1)\n● Require that development include approaches to insure privacy and transparency of data use. (Section 3.1)\n● Track developments in foreign health care systems, looking for useful technologies and also technology failures. (Section 3.1)"
    }
  ]
}
``` 

I want to extract the result as a JSON object without the Markdown ```json prefix  and ``` at the end and only the actual JSON object in Python. What is the way to do this?

result is just a string, so you could e.g. .split("\n") it and take the second to penultimate lines ([1:-1]) for further processing.

Have you tried: result = result[8:-4] before parsing with json?

@jonrsharpe how do I ensure I have taken out ``` from the end as well if we use [1:-1] ?

What do you mean? If it's the last line, why wouldn't it be taken out?

This kind of hack isn't necessary if you use tool-calling correctly; OpenAI and Anthropic are quite good about returning only valid JSON in this case (and some of the tools for driving OSS models go further and have decoder support for discarding any tokens that would result invalid JSON, providing a 100% guarantee).

Assuming that result is a string then you can use:
result = result.replace("```json", "").replace("``` ", "")

Then to convert it to JSON you can use this:
import json
json_result = json.loads(result)


My concern is that if there something nested inside in the content which is ```json what will we do ? Is it possible to remove things focused in the beginning and the end ?

I see. Then you have to use result = result[8:-5]
